# JOIN TRAE FILAS DE MAS

Tags: sql-server, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta donde quiero que me arroje el listado de lo que contiene un envió shipper_no

Cabe mencionar que el envió tiene diferentes ordenes de compra po_no

Solamente que no se por que la consulta me trae ademas delnumero de envio que le solicito otros envio que no le estoy solicitando y con ello tambien otras ordenes de compra

```
SELECT A3.PO_No,A1.Release_No,A1.Quantity,A1.Ship_Date,A1.EDI_Reference_No,A1.PO_Line_Key,A4.Release_Key,A1.Release_Key,A5.Shipper_No,A1.EDI_Key_Add FROM Sales_v_Release_e A1
INNER JOIN Sales_v_PO_Line_e A2 ON A1.PO_Line_Key = A2.PO_Line_Key and A1.Release_Status_Key = 75 AND A1.EDI_Reference_No <> ''
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_PO_e A3 ON A2.Add_By = A3.Add_By AND A2.PO_Key = A3.PO_Key AND A3.PO_Status_Key = 211
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_Shipper_Line_e A4 ON A1.Release_Key = A4.Release_Key
LEFT JOIN Sales_v_Shipper_e A5 ON A4.Shipper_Key = A5.Shipper_Key AND A1.Ship_To = A5.Customer_Address_No AND A5.Shipper_No = 'SH01162'
```

Comment: Por favor no uses mayúsculas sostenidas, eso equivale a gritar

Comment: Además de eso ya probaste con `INNER JOIN` para que solo te traiga registros que tienen un vinculo con la otra tabla, por que `left join` traerá todos los registros incluyendo aquellas filas de la izquierda que no tienen un vínculo en la tabla de la derecha

Comment: O simplemente pon Join